# :after pseudo element is not appearing even it has content property

Tags: html, css, button, pseudo-element

This is my [web page](https://graceamaron.com/update-questions).

After questions fetching, the CSS class '**updating**' will be applied to **update** button while ajax request is going on.

The class has two pseudo elements. ( :before n :after)

But when class added only :before is appearing but not **:after**
(It has content property too)

```
.update-question-form button {
display: inline-block;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Add animation to the update button */

.update-question-form button.updating:before,
.update-question-form button.updating::after {
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

.update-question-form button.updating::after {
content: " ";
background-color: #ccc;
  animation: slide2 1s linear infinite;
}

.update-question-form button.updating:before {
content: '';
background-color: #09316c;
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide1 {
  0% {
    right: -33%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 33%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's working fine, as you can see here:

```css
@keyframes slide1 {
  0% {
    right: -33%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide2 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 33%;
  }
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.button.updating::before,
.button.updating::after {  
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

.button.updating:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
}

.button.updating::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  animation: slide2 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<button class="button updating">Click me!</button>
```

However, in your site there are some other styles that are applyting `display: none` to your `::after` pseudo-element:

```
button::after,
input[type=button]::after,
input[type=reset]::after,
input[type=submit]::after,
.button::after,
.wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link::after,
.added_to_cart::after {
    display: none;
}
```

You can see it in DevTools > Elements > Styles, scrolling all the way to the bottom:

[image]

You have a few ways to fix it:

- Change the selectors above so that they are more specific and do not apply the `display: none;` to all `::after` pseudo-elements.
- Add `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to `.button.updating::after`, as this selector is already more specific than the ones above.
- If the above doesn't work (if the `display` property is still getting overridden by the `display: none` above), you can add `!important` to it, even thought I would encourage you not to use it / abuse it (it's usually a code smell).

Comment: Thank you for finding problem. But then how to achieve this by not changing that display property.

Comment: @PrabhuPaul You could make the selectors that apply `display: none` more specific so that they do not affect elements that shouldn't be affected, or just try adding `display: block` to `.button.updating::after`. If it doesn't work, you can add `display: block !important;` instead, but you should avoid using `!important`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's worked. ```.update-question-form button.updating::before,
.update-question-form button.updating::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  background-color: #09316c;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}

.update-question-form button.updating::after {
  animation: slide2 1s linear infinite;
}

.update-question-form button.updating:before {
  animation: slide1 1s linear infinite;
}```

Comment: Edit your answer according to, and I will mark it as ```Answer```

Comment: However, is there any way to make those two elements as one single :before element ?

Comment: @PrabhuPaul You could use CSS gradients. Just spend some time playing around with that, you should be able to draw the diagonal lines pattern you want with that.